# Unable to click on href element

Tags: selenium

I have element as below

```
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="fttSelectCase('247137'); post(this, null, 'select');">247137</a>
</td>
```

On main screen link appear as "247137" on which I need to click.

I tried as

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='theCase']/tbody/tr/td[3]/a"))).click();
```

but it's not clicking the element and returning `NoSuchElementException`.

I tried various ways like till the element visible, `JavascriptExecutor` but no luck.

Comment: can you please share your html code or link?

Comment: You have doubled `By.xpath`. Fix it.

Comment: can you share URL?

Comment: your xpath is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Following xpath may help you:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[contains(text(),'247137')])
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I cant use above as I am passing input 247137 in a textbox then search for this particular id (247137) I have this value in my datapool sheet using datadriven framework. I am reading value & sending to textbox & clicking search after search it appear as a link 247137. Which defined as below HTML path<td> <a href="#" onclick="fttSelectCase('247281'); post(this, null, 'select');">247281</a></td> But when I use driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Clickusecaseid‌​"))).click(); (Clickusecaseid=.//*[@id='theCase']/tbody/tr/td[3]/a – defined in property file) It’s not clicking on 247137

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that selenium web driver supports **linkText** and **partialLinkText** so if the text is unique you may be able to use the examples below.

Here is a Java example of find by "linkText" then click:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("247137")).click();
```

Or you could also use "partialLinkText" then click:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("247137")).click();
```

Comment: I cant use above as I am passing input 247137 in a textbox then search for this particular id (247137) I have this value in my datapool sheet using datadriven framework. I am reading value & sending to textbox & clicking search after search it appear as a link 247137. Which defined as below HTML path<td> <a href="#" onclick="fttSelectCase('247281'); post(this, null, 'select');">247281</a></td>
But when I use  driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Clickusecaseid"))).click();
(Clickusecaseid=.//*[@id='theCase']/tbody/tr/td[3]/a – defined in property file) It’s not clicking on 247137

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this resolved.
 WebElement Clickusecaseid = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Clickusecaseid")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Clickusecaseid);